# How to pass user submitted form data into the success_url in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to pass the user submitted form data into the url kwargs. As of now I am directely returning the redirect response within the form_valid methoad of django's class based views.

```
class BillsSelectMonthView(GetFormKwargsMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SelectMonthAndCustomerForm
    template_name = 'customers/bills_select_month.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customers:bills_select_month')
    current_page_name = PAGE_NAME_BILLS

    def form_valid(self, form):
        month_year = form.cleaned_data['month']
        self.customer = form.cleaned_data['customer']
        return redirect(
            'customers:bills_preview', 
            month= int(month_year.month), 
            year = int(month_year.year), 
            customer_id = int(self.customer.pk))
```

But, with this approach some of the django's other internal methoad will be skipped. I am just wondering is there any other or better way to do the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `get_success_url()` method for this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(
        "customers:bills_preview", kwargs={"month": self.month, ...}
    )
```

Just save the needed values for `get_success_url()` in `form_valid()`.